# Error 'Invalid desktop entry file:' when using web browser in LXDE

Tags: lxde, browser, .desktop

My system is Linux Lubuntu 17.10 and Firefox is installed as a browser. It can be accessed through the application panel, but clicking on the Web Browser Icon on the Task Bar leads to the following error:

> Invalid desktop entry file:
>   '/usr/share/applications/lxde-x-www-browser.desktop'

I have tried

```
desktop-file-validate lxde-x-www-browser.desktop
```

but this did not change anything.

Here are the contents of the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Name=Web Browser  
Name[pt_BR]=Navegador web  
Name[zh_TW]=瀏覽器  
GenericName=X Web Browser  
GenericName[pt_BR]=Navegador web gráfico  
GenericName[zh_TW]=網頁瀏覽器  
Exec=/usr/bin/x-www-browser %u  
Terminal=false  
Type=Application  
Categories=GTK;WebBrowser;Network  
Icon=web-browser  
NoDisplay=true
```

Comment: Can you show    update-alternatives --display www-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible Solutions

- Goto the equivalent of `Settings → Preferred Applications` and ensure a “default browser” has been selected
- Examine / execute `/usr/bin/x-www-browser` directly and see what happens
- Visit firefox's `about:preferences` and ensure it is checking whether is is the default browser, and see if there is a button active to “make default browser“ or some such thing
- run `desktop-file-validate --warn-kde lxde-x-www-browser.desktop` to check kde-specific fields
- Point `Exec=…` ⇒ `Exec=/usr/bin/firefox` (directly at the firefox executable, wherever that is…)—*see `which firefox` or `whereis firefox` at a terminal if you're having trouble knowing*

Comment: P.S. There are a couple extra spaces on each line in your example code—perhaps check for extraneous spaces/nonprinting characters or strange line endings. `dos2unix` would be an easy fix for CRLF → LF but I don't know if this would be causing anything if it is even the case.

Comment: Tried all of your suggestions, no luck until the last one, which did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I see now I neglected the `%u` which I suppose means that dragging a URL onto the icon won't work—that is I don't think it'll work for file association as there's no place to substitute a filename, although maybe the filename or URL will be appended anyway… haven't read any standard or source and dont't recall what the ‘%u’ exactly indicates.